# change/modify the dropdownlist text by value using kendo ui

Tags: text, drop-down-menu, telerik

I'm working with Teleriks Kendo UI in hope it makes my life easier (not proved yet). Currently I implemented a kendoui dropdownlist (#gamelist) filled up by a JSON php script. That works so fine so far…. 
I would like now to change (not set) a text of an option inside this dropdownlist (I know the value from outside the dropdownlist). I couldn't find anything about changing values and/or text of an option entry at Teleriks example page: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist

I am so far that I can't f.e. display the text with JQuery directly:

```
alert($("#gamelist option:selected").text());
```

-> empty message box

Instead of that I have to do it that way on KendoUI side:

```
var dropdownlist = $("#gamelist").data("kendoDropDownList");
alert(dropdownlist.text());
```

-> Display the current selected entry in dropdownlist

So I am not allowed to change a text of an option like:

```
$('#gamelist option[value=37]').text('Chess');
```

Sounds easy directly with JQuery but doesn't work on Teleriks side. How can I change text inside a dropdownlist in KendoUI? Anyone knows?

Answer (score 0):

After deeper search I could fiddle out the solution. How to change a (specific) option text inside Kendo UI option list:

```
var dropdownlist = $("#gamelist").data("kendoDropDownList");
dropdownlist.dataItem().title = '<desired_text>'; 
dropdownlist.refresh();
```

This will change the option text of the current displayed entry. If you want to change the text of another option you can pass the index value (starting at 0) on dataItem(). The refresh() is important to show up the changed text.